# Как отправить фото нажатием на inline кнопку?

Tags: python, button, aiogram, inline, photo

Помогите пожалуйста написать код где при нажатии на инлайн кнопку код получал запрос на какойто колбек дата и выдавал фото думаю 3 дня но не додумался пишу все на aiogram примерный код который я использую прикреплен снизу но он хоть и не выдает ошибок но и так не работает мда...
Плиз помогите пожалуйста

Код

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda call: True)
async def calls_naprimer(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    if call.data == "button1":
        await message.answer_photo(photo="AgACAgIAAxkBAAIyU2E2IvI_uHqhjorlNFAmvlxxsbWeAAIPtTEbL52xScailMfWbabxAQADAgADeAADIAQ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы обращаетесь к переменной `message`, которой не существует. Для объекта
`CallbackQuery` обращайтесь к объекту `Message` так: `call.message`

```py
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='button1')
async def menu_index(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.answer_photo(photo="AgACAgIAAxkBAAIyU2E2IvI_uHqhjorlNFAmvlxxsbWeAAIPtTEbL52xScailMfWbabxAQADAgADeAADIAQ")
```

Comment: не помогло а еще плюс говорит что тип модули не те  Wrong file identifier/http url specified   что это могло бы значить вроде ве сделал как вы и говорили ...

Comment: и кстати разве не должно быть так если поменять Message на call.message

@dp.message_handler(lambda call: True)
async def calls_naprimer(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    if call.data == "button1":
        await call.message.answer_photo(photo="AgACAgIAAxkBAAIyU2E2IvI_uHqhjorlNFAmvlxxsbWeAAIPtTEbL52xScailMfWbabxAQADAgADeAADIAQ")

Comment: Смотрите Ваш file_id, он не найден в боте. Либо загружайте файл по новой

Comment: Спасибо все работает отлично блогодарю за помощь , и хорошего вам дня и чтоб всегда у вас код работ с первого раза :)

Comment: а если интерестно то просто нужно было поменять айди фото